# Large excel files taking more time to initialize for ClosedXML

Tags: excel, closedxml, closedxml.report

I am using [ClosedXML.0.76.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/0.76.0) in my **MVC 5 C#** project to load the uploaded excel file's data into the object which exists in the MVC controller and afterward displaying data in UI from the object.

To get this, I am using `WorkBook = new XLWorkbook(file.ServerPath)` to initialize/load excel data in the WorkBook object.

Now my question is while I am initializing `XLWorkbook` for a small size excel file, it's working fine but when the excel file is large (approx 4 MB size) then it is taking 5 to 6 seconds to create/initialize `XLWorkbook` object. Is there any way to optimize the time for creating the `XLWorkbook` object for a large excel file?

My large excel file has many unused/blank columns at last. Is there any way to get only used columns and rows while creating/initializing the `XLWorkbook` object so it can speed up initialization if we are not including blank/unused columns for the `XLWorkbook` object?

Comment: As of the time of writing this, the latest version of ClosedXML is 0.95.4. A lot performance improvements have been made since version 0.76.0. Please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have checked with the latest version but it's taking same time as version 0.76.0.